# How to query object array data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have built an application that stores all of my data in a MongoDB with thousands of entries. Now I want to query it from an HTML page. I have been able to successfully load the  data with a button click, but I am unsure as to how to write a query for it. In standard MySQL, I could do something like "SELECT * from dbname where initials = "AA" and sector = "ECHO" " which are fields in the database. I have these fields in my object as well. How would I write the query to achieve the results similar to the MySQL statement above?

This is a sample of the array of objects data being returned:

```
[{_id: {$oid: "58306ce77df6dc1268c87142"}, cjs: "ZV", comment: null, current: false, duration: 50,…},…]
[0 … 99]
0:{_id: {$oid: "58306ce77df6dc1268c87142"}, cjs: "ZV", comment: null, current: false, duration: 50,…}
_id:{$oid: "58306ce77df6dc1268c87142"}
cjs:"ZV"
comment:null
current:false
duration:50
duration_string:null
error:null
expires_at:"2021-10-04T00:41:34.000Z"
fde_id_final:"778152728"
fde_id_initial:"778134619"
function:"SAT.IN"
initials:"AA"
json_class:"SatTransaction"
name:"Al Albert"
ot:false
position:"RDR"
quality:null
satin:"2016-10-05T00:41:34.000Z"
satout:"2016-10-05T01:32:20.000Z"
sector:"ECHO"
shift_date:"2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z"
shift_duration:508
shift_duration_string:null
shift_end:58
shift_start:990
trainee:false
1:{_id: {$oid: "58306ce77df6dc1268c87144"}, cjs: "FY", comment: null, current: false, duration: 51,…}
```

And this is my basic HTML where I use a button to load the entire JSON file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://maccdx170131:4567/api/v1/sat", function(result){

        });
    });
});





</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help or advice!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: What you've quoted is not JSON. In JSON, property names must be in double quotes for a start.

Comment: You are correct - it's not JSON. It's an array of objects. I was getting two of my projects mixed up. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: One normally does queries against the database rather than loading data into memory and trying to do filtering there. MongoDB has query facilities for doing this.  You could start with [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a RESTful api that can handle queries. These can either be included in a header or as query parameters off the end of your url:

`api/v1/sat?dataItem1=12`    the query would have to be encoded (shown here without that for ease of illustration)

Then I would do mongoDB queries from your server code and return that to the client as indicated in other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the query on the server you can use [MongoDB's $and query selector](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/):

```
collection.find({
  $and: [
    {'initials': 'AA'},
    {'sector': 'ECHO'}
  ]
})
```

Obviously you would have to pass the parameters in your AJAX request if the query is to be dynamic.